# Supply current of Nanopower OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-power, pir

I'm using MCP6044 Quad OpAmp ([Datasheet](https://www.dexsilicium.com/Microchip_MCP6041.pdf)) for battery powered PIR sensor, it works fine but draws too much current. When I plug it to 3V source (VDD: 3V, VSS: GND) with no load it draws around 550uA, where I suppose it should be around 3uA (600nA/amp). Let me know if it's something wrong with chip or I do something incorrectly.

**Update:**
There's schematic I used:
[image]

Comment: schematic would help

Comment: Also, are you actually measuring that low a current properly?

Comment: What temperature is the amplifier?

Comment: Are there any inputs or outputs connected, or are just floating and there really is only power pins connected?

Comment: Any digital inputs left floating? These can oscillate in the MHz range, waste power, and possibly fool a current meter.

Comment: The datasheet lists 1uA per amplifier maximum at 25C. It's a tested parameter, so either your amplifier is damaged, you have some kind of oscillation going on, or you're measuring the current incorrectly.  You should have no load on the output (a feedback resistor can be a load in an inverting configuration for example).    I'd think you should hook it up as a unity-gain buffer with the + input at half the supply rail and good decoupling to prevent oscillation, then measure the current.  How are you measuring the current?

Comment: I pulled down those 2 pins (8 and 14 in schematic) but no luck. I'm measuring current with multimeter as shown in the schematic

Comment: Temperature of amplifier is around 27 C after 5 min of working